# How do we find out how many times storage has been added to an AWS RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are seeking for ways to figure out how many times an RDS instance's storage got modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the `configurationchange` DB instance event to receive notifications when the current storage settings for the DB instance are changed.

Refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html) for more details

Comment: Can we query cloud trail events to get the storage addition details over given period of time

Comment: Yes, it can be another way. Amazon RDS activity is recorded in a CloudTrail event in Event history